# Enter the factors of $P(z)=z^4 +4$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am not understanding what I am doing wrong.
$$\begin{align}P(z)&=z^4+4\\&=z^4-(2i)^2\\&=(z^2-2i)(z^2+2i)\\&=(z-1-i)(z+1+i)(z-1+i)(z+1-i)\end{align}$$

Thus, $(z-1-i)(z+1+i)(z-1+i)(z+1-i)$ are the factors, but it is wrong according to Webwork.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  WolframAlpha agrees.

Comment: if you multiply the first factor times the third,   then the second times the fourth, you see a product of two real quadratics; associated with Sophie Germain

Comment: You sure the question isn't looking for real polynomial factors? Because this polynomial famously factors in $\mathbb Z[x].$

Comment: Or maybe the question is looking for all the factors, not just the linear ones?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews At the beginning of the question it states "Every polynomial with real coefficients can be written as the product of irreducible factors with real coefficients." so maybe yes then. Even so, it does not accept $(z^2-2z+2)(z^2+2z+2)$

Comment: Hard to tell what a computer wants, but that isn’t the factors, $z^2-2z+2,$ and $z^2+2z+2$ are the factors. What you’ve given is a factorization, which is related but different. The prime factors of $6$ are $2$ and $3,$ not $2\cdot 3.$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+z%5E4+%2B+4